# Crocodile vs. cocodrile: where does the "r" belong?

Tags: etymology

We are all familiar with crocodiles. We know, love, and recognize them in many European languages:

- German: *Krokodil*
- French: *crocodile*
- Portuguese: *crocodilo*
- Russian: *крокодил*

But perhaps it comes as a surprise that other modern languages put the "r" in a different spot:

- Italian: *coccodrillo*
- Spanish: *cocodrilo*
- Catalan: *cocodril*

The OED gives us the following colorful etymology, which shows all these forms emerging from a corrupt Medieval Latin *cocodrillus*--and, at least in some cases, they were corrected back!

> Middle English cocodrille, cokadrill, etc. < Old French cocodrille (13–17th cent.) = Provençal cocodrilh, Spanish cocodrilo, Italian coccodrillo, **medieval Latin cocodrillus, corruption of Latin crocodīlus** (also corcodilus), < Greek κροκόδειλος, found from Herodotus downward. **The original form after Greek and Latin was restored in most of the modern languages in the 16–17th cent.**: French crocodile (in Paré), Italian crocodillo (in Florio), Spanish crocodilo (in Percival).

I thought this completely answered my question, but I found at least one competing etymology that suggests that the "-drilo" *does* belong! The [The Merriam-Webster New Book of Word Histories](https://books.google.com/books?id=IrcZEZ1bOJsC&pg=PA125)
--which is echoed also by the etymology given in a Google word search--says the following:

> [alteration (influenced by Latin *crocodilus*) of Middle English *cocodrille*, from Old French, from Medieval Latin *cocodrillus*, alteration of Latin *crocodilus*, *corcodillus*, from Greek ***krokodeilos, krokodilos*, alteration of (assumed) *krokodrilos*, from *krokē* pebble + *drilos* worm**]

(abbreviations expanded)

I have a lot of related quetions:

- Is the latter etymology just wrong about the supposed origin in Greek "krokodrilos"?
- If not, is it pure happenstance that the Medieval "corruption" of *crocodilus* happened to move the "r" to a place that it existed originally?
- Most importantly: **Why shouldn't we start pedantically over-correcting to "crocodriles"?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "pebble-worm" derivation seems rather doubtful. Of the etymological dictionaries, Frisk and Chantraine accept it, but Beekes says it "should be forgotten". I can't find any direct evidence of a word δρῖλος meaning "worm"; here's what I've found:

1. Hesychius lists a word [δρίλαξ](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0057%3Aentry%3Ddri%2Flac) meaning "leech", which is pretty close.
2. [δρῖλος](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0057%3Aentry%3Ddri%3Dlos) itself appears to be a δὶς λεγόμενον: it appears once in an inscription at Amphissa to which I don't have access at the moment (*Supp.Epigr.* 2.353), and once in the *Anthologia Palatina*, in [this rather opaque couplet](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Anth.%20Gr.%2011.197&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A2008.01.0475):

> ἤθελε ‘ΔΡΙΜΥΣ’ ἄγαν τὸ πρόσθ᾽ Ἱερώνυμος εἶναι:
>   νῦν δὲ τὸ ΔΡΙ μὲν ἔχει, ΛΟΣ δὲ τὸ ΜΥΣ γέγονεν.
>   "Drimus once wanted too much to be Hieronymus: now he has the *Dri-*, but the *-mus* has become *-los*".

Chantraine adds that δρῖλος is glossed in Latin as *verpus*, which L&S [define](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/resolveform?type=exact&lookup=verpus&lang=la) as "a circumcised man". I'm not sure how you get from any of this to "worm" (though *verpus* is pretty close to *[verpa](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dverpa)*, which means "penis"). Maybe the Amphissa inscription would explain things.

In any case if the word really was originally κροκόδριλος then a dissimilatory loss of the second ρ would be very plausible, as would a subsequent unrelated metathesis in medieval Latin / Spanish etc.

To your last question I'd say the obvious answer is "because you'd be stared at like a crazy person".

Answer (score 3):

My guess is the following: the appearance and disappearance of liquid consonants is very common among languages, for instance, latin *parabola* became *palavra* in portuguese, and *mīrāculum* became *milagre*, in both these cases by a process we call "metathesis". The word indeed came from *krókē* + *drîlos* and it changed by means of making its articulation easier. So *krokódeilos* became one greek form and it was borrowed by latin speakers and it became *crocodīlus*. A later latin form, changed by making the articulation easier, a spontaneous process, was *cocodrillus, and it generated the descendants you showed. The forms like *crocodilo* and *crocodile* were borrowed later from latin.